# Removing second extension from file name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I have files like below:

```
Filename.txt
Filename.txt.new
Filename2.txt
Filename2.txt.new
```

I want to remove the "new" keyword for the files ending with "new"

also when we do this, existing file will also have same name, so i want to overwrite the same with the contents of the files ending with "new"

Comment: Please do **not** double-post!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly this is a case where `ren *.foo *.bar` won't work, but we can do it with a simple loop:

```
for %x in (*.new) do move /y "%x" "%~nx"
```

This simply loops over all files that have a `.new` extension (you could also do the same only for `*.txt.new`) and renames them. `%~nx` removes the extension from the name, in this case the `.new`.

When using this in a batch file you have to double the `%` signs:

```
for %%x in (*.new) do move /y "%%x" "%%~nx"
```

Comment: thanks what if i want to do for sub folders as well?

Comment: Add `/r` after `for`.

Comment: For the sake of readability I would advise against using a FOR variable that is the same letter case as a for variable modifier.  For readability I always use an upper case letter for the FOR variable otherwise you could easily confuse the lower case x as the extension modifier. `for %%G in (*.new) do move "%%G" "%%~nG"`

Comment: @Squashman: Considering the last letter is always the variable I wouldn't call that easily confusable. But you're of course free to make your own conventions.

Comment: Let me give you a scenario. Might be hard to read in the comments. Lets say you want to add a lower case x to the extension of these file names. **CODE:** `for %x in ("file 1.xls" "File 2.xls") do echo %~xx` **OUTPUT** `.xls .xls`. In order to make the x variable work you would need to specify the n and x modifier: `echo %~nxx` But if your for variable is a lower case g or Upper case G there is no problem just using the for variable directly. `for %g in ("file 1.xls" "File 2.xls") do echo %~gx`. **Output:** `file 1.xlsx file 2.xlsx`

Comment: And lets say you just wanted to add a lower case x to the extension. `for %x in ("file 1.xls" "File 2.xls") do echo %~xxx`.  This code outputs `.xls .xls`. You can't do it with the x being the for variable.

Comment: You probably want to add the `/Y` option to automatically overwrite without prompt. You also probably want to add `>nul` to suppress the `1 file(s) moved.` message.

Comment: @dbenham: In my test it overwrote it without the /y, unless i added it and forgot. can't check anymore, the folder is gone already.

Comment: @Joey: yes, `move` works slightly different in batch and command line. See last sentence of `move /?`

Comment: @Stephan: Ah, good point. So it was correct before already :-)

Comment: @Stephan (and Joey) - Not quite. The command will prompt within a batch script if the `/Y` option is not used ***and*** the environment variable `COPYCMD=/-Y` is defined.